# How to input a primary key from one table and get information from other tables for that key

Tags: sql, oracle, select, procedure

If I input a value from one table, how do I get the data for that value from other tables? For example, when I type in the invoice number (saleinv) from the saleinv table, how do I get data like the customer's name (cname) and street (cstreet) from the customer table? I have this code here but it doesn't work in SQL Developer. The compiler log says "Statement ignored", referring to the SELECT INTO statement in my procedure. It also highlights the FROM statement in the same thing.

```
  --Procedure
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE saleinvSearch
(
  v_saleinv IN saleinv.saleinv%TYPE,
  v_saleinvInfo OUT saleinv%ROWTYPE
)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT s.saleinv, s.saledate, s.salesman, s.fire, s.liability, s.collision, s.property, s.tradeserial, s.tradeallow, 
       cus.cname, cus.cstreet, cus.ccity, cus.cprov, cus.cpostal, cus.chphone, 
       c.serial, c.make, c.model, c.cyear, c.color, 
       i.saleinv, i.ocode, i.saleprice, o.ocode
  INTO v_saleinvInfo
  FROM saleinv s, customer cus, car c, invoption i, options o
 WHERE s.cname = cus.cname
   AND c.serial = s.serial
   AND i.saleinv = s.saleinv
   AND i.ocode = o.ocode
   AND s.saleinv = v_saleinv;
END;
/
  --Test
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
ACCEPT p_saleinv PROMPT 'Enter a saleinv number: ';
DECLARE
  v_saleinv saleinv%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  saleinvSearch(UPPER('&p_saleinv'), v_saleinv);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('         ' || 'SPECIALTY IMPORTS' || CHR(13));
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('           ' || 'SALES INVOICE' || CHR(10));
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Invoice No.: ' || v_saleinv.saleinv || CHR(9) || 'Date: ' || v_saleinv.saledate || CHR(13));
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SOLD TO:  Name: ' || v_saleinv.cname || CHR(13));
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('       Address: ' || v_saleinv.cstreet || CHR(13));
END;
/
```

Comment: Well, if you execute your select statement alone in sql developer (without the INTO clause and hardcode a value for v_saleinv, what is the result?

Comment: @OldProgrammer It seems to give me the results I want, but I also want to be able to take that information from the procedure to the testing script. Does it have to do with the OUT variable that I used?

Comment: You would usually see more than just 'statement ignored'. What is the full error stack? It seems rather unlikely your `saleInv%rowtype` would have the columns from all the tables you're joining to; so are you getting a not-enough-values error?

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes that is what shows up. I'm assuming that instead of `saleInv%rowtype` I would use a variable for every value that I want?

Comment: Or an object type, or a record type (defined in a package so your test script can use it too), or a ref cursor. One variable per column is simple, but you'd have a lot of out parameters and corresponding local variables in your test script. I assume this is a learning exercise.